# Rails karmi/tire configuration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tire

The basic problem is:

I have rails-based website and ElasticSearch db. I changed `index_name` property, but query still looks like:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/index_name/model_name/_search?...
```

So it searches through documents with `_type:'search'`, but in Elastic I have records with `_type:'doc'`.

Is there some ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reindexing,

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS=Model FORCE=true
```